# What is an adjective for somebody who thinks they are helping you but actually aren't?

Tags: single-word-requests, north-american-english

I was wondering what word could describe a person[s] that is trying to help somebody and feels like they are being empathetic towards them, but is trying to be ignored by the other person? I was thinking "falsely-empathetic" or "anti-empathetic", but it sounds to me like the character I'm describing is not trying to help at all?

Comment: I got confused about who's doing what, but maybe you're looking for *empathetic*.

Comment: To clarify, if I understand correctly: Alice wants to be left alone. Bob tries to help Alice. Bob is genuinely trying to be helpful, but he has failed to understand Alice's feelings -- her wish to be left alone. So he is not being empathetic. What is a word for the kind of person Bob is being when he offers unwelcome help and does not know it is unwelcome?

Answer (score 2):

If the person is trying to help because they are nosey, then [busybody](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/busybody) would fit. If they are sincerely trying to help, but the attention is unhelpful or unwanted, then [do-gooder](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-gooder) would be more suitable.